# JavaFX - ComboBox update fetching data from another controller

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

Here is my little Problem :

```
@FXML 
private ComboBox<Person> personcb;
private ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private ResourceBundle langBundle;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        this.Stage = primaryStage;
        this.Stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        rootLayout = initRootLayout(Locale.getDefault());
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("any.css").toExternalForm());
        Stage.setScene(scene);
        Stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    langBundle = resources;
    lblTextByController.setText(langBundle.getString("key1"));
    personcb.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Person> observable,
                Person oldValue, Person newValue) {
            System.out.println("value updated");
        }
    });
}

@FXML
    private void persons() {
        try{
            if(personcb.getItems() == null || personcb.getItems().size() != secondController.getUSER().getPersons().size()){
                ObservableList<Person> persons= 
                        FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                options.addAll(secondController.getUSER().getPersons());
                personcb.setItems(persons);
                personcb.setPromptText(langBundle.getString("key402") +" [" + personcb.size()+"]");
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
        }
    }
```

In my FXML file, the combobox is defined as :

```
<ComboBox fx:id="personcb" onShowing="#persons" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="%key402">
```

I want to add Items after `initialize()` of my **first Controller from my second Controller**.

My current solution works only if I select an item in my ComboBox to update the other ones.

---

### **EDIT** - More Information

My first controller managed the root Pane and contain as root an `BorderPane` with some `buttons` to login and the `ComboBox`. After the user login is done, my second controller is loaded by the following code sample.

```
AnchorPane barHolder = (AnchorPane) overviewLoader.load(); 
BorderPane root = (BorderPane) loginwithsec.getScene().getRoot();
root.setCenter(barHolder);
```

`loginwithsec` is here an button defined `@FXML` doc at my `first controller`.

`overviewLoader` is the FXMLLoader for second controller.

Now, the user shall select a `Person` on the ComboBox of the `first Controller` managed Pane.

The overview (2nd Controller) `load the data` by *some DAO's AFAIK Hibernate for the current selections*. So the lazy loaded DAO's must be filled up in the `ComboBox` automatically to show the users that some Persons are available.

Comment: Are you calling `persons()` when you select an item in the combobox?

Comment: currently yes, but that's the bad way cuz it update's the list only by selecting an item. May i hope theres a way to update them automaticlly if i add an items to the list by another controller.

Comment: Why don't you call the method from `intialize()`. This way the combobox items will be updated while the fxml is loaded.

Comment: mhm, that worked also sure but the data for the cb while init isn't mandatory.  the call of person by event was my try to Update themself by adding some testperson but it only works if i clicked on some selections.

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking. Can you try to explain it better?

Comment: Sure, i've a little tool that managed some Users like an CRM.

Comment: I still didn't get what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: My first controller mangaged the root Pane and contain as root an BorderPane with some btn's to login and my ComboBox.  After the User login is done my second controller load the overview by the following code sample.
AnchorPane barHolder = (AnchorPane) overviewLoader.load();
BorderPane root = (BorderPane) loginwithsec.getScene().getRoot();
root.setCenter("barHolder");
loginwithsec is here an btn defined @FXML doc at my first controller

Comment: Now the User shall select a Person on the ComboBox of the first Controller managed Pane. The Overview (2nd Controller) load the Data by some  DAO's afaik Hibernate for the current selections. So the lazy loaded DAO's musst be filled up in the ComboBox automatilly to show the users that some Persons are availbe. Hope now u understand my Problem.

Comment: I am not sure but your problem seems to transfer the data loaded in second controller made available to the ComboBox in the first controller. Have I comprehended it correctly?

Comment: yep that the Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider you have two controllers and call them

- ParentController
- ChildController

The `ParentController` has a `ObservableList parentList` which is used as the items in the `ComboBox`.

```
public class ParentController {
    ...
    private ObservableList parentList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ...
}
```

The `ChildController` has a `ObservbleList childList` which is populated from the database using hibernate (or whatsoever). We need to pass this data back to the `parentList` to populate its data.

```
public class ChildController {
    ...
    private ObservableList childList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ...
}
```

We expose the `childList` via a public method

```
public class ChildController {
    ...
    private ObservableList childList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList getChildList() {
        return childList;
    }
    // Some logic to load the list    
    ...
}
```

Coming back to `ParentController`, since we are using `ObservableList` instead of `List`, we can take advantage and bind the data of both the list in parent and child controllers. `Bindings.bindContentBidirectional()` makes sure, any change in either of the list will be reflected in the other.

```
public class ParentController {
    ...
    @FXML
    ComboBox comboBox;  

    private ObservableList parentList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void initialize() {
       comboBox.setItems(parentList);
       Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(parentList, childController.getChildList());
    }
    ...
}
```